Can't get custom axis tick values to work in vega-lite for date field
For reference, I've got a line chart where I show one point per week (x), based on the first day of the week, across multiple years (color). However, I don't want the X axis to read as W01-W52 because it's more intuitive to show what month the week occurs in. So I want the axis ticks to begin on the first of each month.
This is how I have it formatted currently (using Clojure so using .EDN instead of .JSON but should be easy to see what I'm doing).
   {:x {:title "Week"
        :timeUnit "week"
        :field :WeekBeginning
        :type "temporal"
        :axis {:format "%b"
               :labelExpr "datum.label[0]"
               :tickCount 12}}

Unfortunately, the ticks don't start at the beginning of each month this way, so for example the "Feb" tick/line is in the middle of February, with some of the points in front of it and some after it.
When I try to set the ticks explicitly, like this, I don't get any ticks at all:
   {:x {:title "Week"
        :timeUnit "week"
        :field :WeekBeginning
        :type "temporal"
        :axis {:format "%b"
               :labelExpr "datum.label[0]"
               :ticks true
               :values ["2024-01-01" "2024-02-01" "2024-03-01" "2024-04-01"
                        "2024-05-01" "2024-06-01" "2024-07-01" "2024-08-01"
                        "2024-09-01" "2024-10-01" "2024-11-01" "2024-12-01"]}}

Anyone ever done something like this successfully?

Can you supply a spec in the online VL editor?

   {:x {:title "Week"
        :timeUnit "yearmonthdate"
        :field :WeekBeginning
        :axis {:format "%b"
               :labelAlign "left"
               :labelExpr "datum.label[0]"
               :timeUnit "month"
               :tickCount 12}}

Update: I ended up shifting the timeUnit of the lines to "yearmonthdate" and the timeUnit of the axis to "month" and was able to get it to format the way I wanted.
